# Merge html theme into rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I just purchased theme and want to implement it into my rails app.  I would want some help as to where files and folders go to in rails app.
I have

CSS folder

- sass
- vendors
- fonts
- screen.css
- screen.css.map
- screen.sass

JS Folder

- options.js
- vendors

Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Sass goes into `app/assets/stylesheets`, javascript into `app/assets/javascripts`, fonts into `app/assets/fonts`. Make sure to read the [Rails assets documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more information.